# How should I configure user comments in Mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, encoding, comments

Well, I've been working on a blog developed from scratch, but I encountered a mayor problem, when a user makes a comment, the form asks for Name and Comment which are almacened in:

```
`comname` VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
```

and

```
`comment` VARCHAR( 1000 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
```

Respectively, but if the user inputs html tags, when php displays the information from MySQL, it displays html, I don't want this to happen. For example when an user writes:

```
<span style="#0F0">Hello world</span>
```

as comment, It displays the text "Hello world" in green.

Is there any way to avoid this, for example, encoding <> characters to display them the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the methods `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` to convert the HTML tags to text. You should even do so because unchecked sending of the content to the database can lead to a vulnerability called SQL Injection where your data can be corrupted or lost. So be sure to escape the characters before storing them in the database.

Comment: Now that you mection it, I do in fact have all the input values escaped with `mysql_real_escape_string()` would that be enough?

Comment: For the case of SQL Injection this is sufficient. But this does not escape the HTML characters. Therefore one of the other functions would be better.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, Now, I'm using `mysql_real_escape_string()` for submitting and `htmlentities()` for showing the information from the database.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a storage issue. This is an output issue. You should be using [**`htmlentities()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to escape the HTML output.

Comment: Thanks! really useful, I was already thinking in using it but I was not sure if that was the way it worked, solved my problem in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to  use `htmlentities`

```
echo  htmlentities($comment);
```

### [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: They indicated they want the HTML tags to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql_real_escape_string` before storing in database although you should be looking at using pdo now MySQL is depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your output with `htmlspecialchars()` it will encode your `<` or `>` with the proper encoding and display HTML as it should:

```
&lt;span style="color:#0F0"&gt;Hello world&lt;/span&gt;
```

giving you the desired display in your output:

here is the info in PHP: http://id.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

The translations performed are:

- '&' (ampersand)
- '"' (double quote)
- "'" (single quote)
- '<' (less than)
- '>' (greater than)